# How do I fix this Kryo exception when using a UDF on hive?

Tags: hive, hortonworks-sandbox, apache-tez

I have a hive query that worked in hortonworks 2.6 sandbox, but it doesn't work on sandbox ver. 3.0 because of this exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 95                                                                                                          
Serialization trace:                                                                                                                                                                                               
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.reducesink.VectorReduceSinkLongOperator)                                                                                                                    
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorFilterOperator)                                                                                                                                        
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)                                                                                                                                                  
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137)                                                                                            
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)                                                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:185)
```

How do I fix it?

I have seen some answers suggesting doing `set hive.exec.parallel=false;` but it doesn't work, I still get this error.

I checked the versions of libraries that I use and made sure that `hadoop version` and `hive --version` match the versions of libraries that I use in my jar.

I also tried this: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150199/orgapachehivecomesotericsoftwarekryokryoexception-1.html it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to run my queries after I reduced the size of my `udf.jar`. It used to be 150 mb and I reduced it to 50 kb. It seems like a kryo bug. I got this info from here:
https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/issues/307

I reduced the size of my `udf.jar` by marking all dependencies as `provided`. So I went from this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!--Notice this line-->
</dependency>
```

This is definitely a kryo bug, because I was able to run this query with that large `udf.jar` file in hortonworks 2.6.

I hope someone finds this information valuable.

Answer (score -1):

I actually referred to this thread of hive https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7711
the comment by Dr.Christian Betz on this issue suggests implementing DoNothingSerializer to solve this exception. I tried implementing that solution and the problem was solved. However, I could not understand the details of how adding Serializer is solving this issue.
Find the solution at this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7711?focusedCommentId=16798855&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16798855]).
Try implementing following Serializer for the class which extends GenericUDF.

```
import org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;

import org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer;

import org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;

import org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;



public class DoNothingSerializer extends Serializer<App> {



@Override

public App read(Kryo arg0, Input arg1, Class<App> arg2) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return new App();

}



@Override

public void write(Kryo arg0, Output arg1, App arg2) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub



}



}
```